# How to hide shapes in a plotly.js plot?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to display a graph with vertical limit of some color, but in certain output cases,
The y bar values are much lower than the upper limit of the set value, I would like to hide not generate those "shapes" like shown below, I would like the red line to not populate the graph so the y-values dont get artificially compressed

[image]

Comment: Also I am having a hard tie defining the x0 and x1 for this graph since the x values are not only a linear access but along text values.As you can see, it doesnt properly cover the graph.

Comment: can you include the `plotly.js` code you used to produce this bar chart? that could help me figure out why the y limits are being set higher than your actual bars